# Android - DatePicker how to keep set current date

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I have custom DatePicker using library from https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs
I use that library because I need to change the color, etc.

And my code now look like this:

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private TextView birthdate;
        private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
        private DatePicker datePicker;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editprofile);
        birthdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.birthdateTextView);
        birthdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
              setCustomDate();
              }
        });

        /* final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); */

        }

        public void setCustomDate() {

                new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                        .title(R.string.pilih_tanggal)
                        .customView(R.layout.datepicker_layout, true)
                        .positiveText(R.string.ok_caps)
                        .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPositive(final MaterialDialog dialog) {
                                super.onPositive(dialog);
                                datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
                                datePicker.init(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                }
                                });
                         birthdate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                         .append(datePicker.getDayOfMonth())
                         .append("").append(datePicker.getMonth())
                         .append("-").append(datePicker.getYear()));
                        }
                        })
                        .positiveColorRes(R.color.ColorPrimary)
                        .negativeText(R.string.cancel)
                        .negativeColorRes(R.color.ColorPrimary)
                        .show();
        }
```

So, I'm success make the TextView as a current date that I set from DatePicker, but the problem is when I tap the TextView again, the date going back to last date (default).

[image]

Above is when Im going to pick the date.
Below is when I successfully make the text to selected date.

[image]

But sadly, when I tap the TextView again, the date back to default, not to my selected date.

[image]

Could someone give me a direction to resolve that? What I know so far is use

> OnDateSetListener

But how to do that with the library also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a few couple days ago I found the solution like this:

```
public void setCustomDate() {
        MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title(R.string.pilih_tanggal)
                .customView(R.layout.datepicker_layout, true)
                .positiveText(R.string.ok_caps)
                .callback(new MaterialDialog.ButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive(final MaterialDialog dialog) {
                        super.onPositive(dialog);
                        birthdate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                                .append(datePicker.getDayOfMonth()).append("/").append(datePicker.getMonth() + 1).append("/").append(datePicker.getYear()));
                    }
                })
                .positiveColorRes(R.color.ColorPrimary)
                .negativeText(R.string.cancel)
                .negativeColorRes(R.color.ColorPrimary)
                .show();

        datePicker = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        datePicker.init(mYear, mMonth, mDay, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
            }
        });
 }
```

I need to initialize the datepicker outside the .callback, so when activity run the datepicker will recognized first. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you would have to create another separate datepicker that gets the day/month/year to be set from getting the text from your textview?  If that does not help, let me know and I can delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
            R.style.DatePicker, datePickerListener,
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

 datePicker.updateDate(1988,9,8);
```